# Express does not show request body on form data on using body parser and multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, webhooks

In Index.js I have added bodyparser and bodyparser url encoder as middleware.

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3032;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

In other file I have just console logged the request body and it logs out an empty object.

```
webhooks.post("/webhooks/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("ok");
});
```

the res.body is still `{}`

Comment: do you set  'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' in the header?

Comment: Can you describe more about what's in the incoming request and what is its content-type?  And, where does the variable `webhooks` come from?  What is that?  Is that an Express router or something else?

Comment: I was able to solve this isse by adding `app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/plain" }));`
as a middleware to the application. `using app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` did not solve it. Thanks for asking @MohammadYaserAhmadi